# How to plot a specific data with different color in Python, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

The code below plots the gauss function in a graph.

And I want the `center` in the code presents in different color.

Is there any approach I can do?

```
plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))

plt.grid(True)

x = np.linspace(0,11, 100)
center = np.mean(x)
print(center) # This is the only point what I would like to give different color
gauss_function = np.exp(-((x-center)**2)/2**2)
plt.plot(x, gauss_function, marker='o')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZQ62.png)

Thank you so much for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
# compute red point coordinates
point_x = center
point_y = np.exp(-((center-point_x)**2)/2**2)

plt.scatter(point_x, point_y, marker='o', color='red', s=50, zorder=3)
```

where `s=50` defines the size of the red marker, while `zorder=3` is used to put the red marker over the current (Gaussian) graph